# Typed Query in Entity Manager, the generic way

Tags: generics, jpql, createquery, typedquery

I read this article: https://www.baeldung.com/simplifying-the-data-access-layer-with-spring-and-java-generics

And i have a question for this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).getResultList();
    }
```

For me here the List should be more replaced with List<?> because the type checking here is not really done.
But there exists a derived TypedQuery also, so why not use this instead?
Could this code not written as:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName(), clazz).getResultList();
    }
```

To use the TypedQuery and then really get the List a result?

The other question is the term "from " + clazz.getName()) itself.
Am I right, this is just a short form without the Select?
I would have written this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("Select t from " + clazz.getName() + " t", clazz).getResultList();
    }
```

I could not find anything about this form, just starting with a "from ..."
In the literature I use for research, there was always a

```
createQuery("Select ....") etc,
```

I tried my code examples above and for me it looked like it works... just want to get more information on this case.
Maybe im on the wrong way?